# Get data of another child in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm making a Board which can write comments.

All functions work well.

But the only thing I need is displaying profile of the author of the comment.

```
{{ board.title }}
{{ board.text }}

{% for comment is context.commentmodel_set.all %}
    {{ comment.comment }}
    {{ comment.whose.profile??? }} <- ????
{% endfor %}
```

////////////// EDIT [Add Models] ///////////

```
# Appname : board / model
class Board(models.Model):
    whose = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    whose = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


# Appname : accounts / model
class Profile(models.Model):
    whose = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_need = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    tel = models.CharField()
```

/////Edit second [Views.comment] //////

```
@login_required
def comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.post = Board.objects.get(pk=pk)
            post.whose = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('board_detail', pk)
        else:
            print('TurminalCheck : Invalid!!')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'boardapp/board.html', context)
```

The image for reference is attached below.
[image]

Comment: Can you show comment, user and profile models?

Comment: Wouldn't it be just `{{ comment.whose.profile.i_need }}`? But you should show the actual models.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner  I've just updated. im using Django User system. so i don't have user model. that's all.

Comment: Looks like code suggested by  Daniel Roseman should work. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried. but it doesn't work..

Comment: I've updated again to add views for comment. Should I write someting about Profile in the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add related name whose field in Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    whose = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    i_need = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    tel = models.CharField()
```

After you can call profile with {{comment.whose.profile}}

Comment: Thank you so much :) Very simple and clean!